# What is the power of Bell Borca on opponent's turns?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Bell Borca, Spectral Sergeant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bell%20Borca%2C%20Spectral%20Sergeant) enters the battlefield as a 0/5, and gets power when something gets exiled. Does the power hold till the next of the controller's upkeep, or does it get reset to a 0/5 each upkeep?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Bell Borca, Spectral Sergeant's power is equal to the greatest number noted for it *this turn.*

(emphasis mine)

So its power gets reset every upkeep (well, actually somewhat earlier, there is an untap step happen before the upkeep), not just its controller's. The reset happens as soon as the turn begins, so [Meekstone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Meekstone) has no effect on Bell Borca (unless, of course, it has a permanent power buff because of e.g. an equipment).

Comment: Makes sense, but the entire LGS was wrong on this then, including the judges.

Comment: With all due respect, your judges need to go back to judge school then. This is not a particularly complicated ruling, and is even covered on Gatherer: "before any cards are noted for it each turn, Bell Borca’s power is 0."

Comment: A small follow up question: Does the power reset happen before or after untapping your permanents? That would be relevant for [Meekstone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=425811) for example

Comment: @IvoBeckers good question, answer updated

Comment: @Glorfindel technically it would happen during the player's cleanup step, like all other effects that refer to a duration by turns.

Comment: @Andrew not sure ... the cleanup step is for 'until end of turn' things. This has a slightly different wording (perhaps because it's a characteristic defining ability?)

Comment: Maybe - though it's something of a moot point anyways since there's nothing else that happens which could make it matter between cleanup and the start of the next turn's untap step.

Comment: @Glorfindel The cleanup step is also for "this turn" effects (CR 514.2: "all “until end of turn” and “this turn” effects end.") so I think it power gets reset to zero at that point. That does give the small window for something to happen if something else put a trigger on the stack in the cleanup step.

Comment: @PhilipKendall sounds like you can make a new question out of that :)

Comment: It seems to me that the power simply is the highest CMC. Any time anything in the game checks its power, the game looks at the highest CMC.  It getting set isn't really a game event. It's like any other continuous effect.  If a card says that its power is equal to your  life points, then when your life points change, the card's power does too. There's no delay. The power changing doesn't use the stack or require SBA being checked or anything else. The power just is the new value.

Comment: @Acccumulation true, but the difference is a card with a CDA based on life total like [Malignus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240062) Is looking at a statistic that just is what it is throughout the game, where this one specifies that it is looking at the results of an event "this turn"  so the question is when does that change. And the two reasonable answers are at the start of untap (first step of first phase of next turn) and at the cleanup (when all other 'this turn' effects end)

Comment: @Andrew It seems to me that there is only one reasonable answer to the question of when "this turn" changes: it changes when the turn changes. From the moment the turn begins, the new value applies. When does the value of storm count change? Does it change at the cleanup step, or does it change the moment the next turn starts?